# Как в JavaScript сделать регулярное вырожение соответствующее X, если перед X стоит Y?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

`/X(?=Y)/` соответствует X, eсли после X следует Y, а мне нужно чтобы Y было перед X. Т.е. Мне нужно такое регулярное выражение, которое соответствовало `'X'` в строках `"YX"` или `"abcYXde"`, но не соответствовало `'X'` в строках `"XY"`, `"abYcXde"` или `"abXXY"`. Я думал, что таким регулярным вырожением будет `\(?=Y)X\`, но это почему-то не работает.

Comment: Блок предварительного просмотра назад - `(?<=Y)X`

Comment: а просто поменять местами X и Y в исходном выражении нельзя? Ведь "Y было перед X" соответствует "после Y следует X", а это как раз исходное выражение, только наоборот.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте ***блок предварительного просмотра назад*** — `(?<=Y)X`.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Svd9sH/1/).

"**Положительный** *блок предварительного просмотра назад*" находит *позицию* в строке, *сразу перед* которой имеется совпадение определённых в данном блоке последовательности шаблонов.

"**Отрицательный** (негативный) *блок предварительного просмотра назад*" находит *позицию* в строке, *сразу перед* которой НЕТ совпадения определённых в данном блоке последовательности шаблонов.

Это значит, что `(?<=Y)X` не найдёт совпадения в `YabcX`. `(?<=Y.*?)X` найдёт такое совпадние, но тут нужно учитывать тот факт, что не все библиотеки регулярных выражений поддерживают блоки предварительного просмотра назад с шаблонами неопределённой длины (с квантификаторами типа `*`, `?`, `{8,}`, `+`). [.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference), [PyPi *regex*](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), [JGSoft Sofware](https://www.just-great-software.com/), JavaScript ECMAScript 2018 (см. [таблицу совместимости](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/)) поддерживают такой синтаксис.

См. [пример работы выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DY.*%3F%29X&i=YabcX%0D%0AYabcX%20YabcX).

Comment: если Y должен присутствовать в рамках одного слова то лучне использовать нечто такое`(?<=Y[^ ]*)X`, либо `[^\t ]`. потому что в вашем случае с .* выберет X и первый и второй в случае строки `YabcX abcX`

Comment: @PotroNik Это всего лишь примеры. Если между `Y` и `X` могут находиться только буквы, то надо вместо `.` использовать `\p{L}` / `[[:alpha:]]`. Это уже частные случаи.